# I Love Rebus Puzzles!

Tags: rebus, video-games

This rebus puzzle is going to be related to some of my favorite games

1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

other word for

[image]

2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

3.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

> Call of Duty

2.

> Clash Royale

3.

> Mobile Legends

Comment: +1 --> All correct. I may have picked games that are too popular these days.Gonna accept in 10 minutes. :)

Comment: (For what it's worth, I don't think the choice of games is what makes it easy -- it's chosing verbatim wordmarks that gives the games away almost instantly. On another note, I'd prefer if the representation were a bit more concise, so that the whole rebus could be seen without scrolling. For example, you could align each rebus horizontally and do away with the fat plus signs.)

Comment: Noted. Thx for the suggestions :) @MOehm